# Trying to disconnect players

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, pygame

I have been trying to make a multiplayer game with pygame. I'm having a lot of trouble actually disconnecting the player properly.

Whenever i close a client the clients that had been previously opened after don't work anymore. I think the issue is in the server file but i am not quite sure how to fix it. this is the server error:

```
line 50, in threaded_client
    del players[player]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

this is my code [my code](https://github.com/Sietseq/socketTutorial/blob/master/network.py)

Thanks for in advance!

Comment: The problem is that you're addressing players by their position (index) in the list `players`. This is a problem because when you delete a player from the list, the list changes length. So the next time you access the list, the index `player` has a different meaning and can, like in this case, lead to out-of-range errors.

Comment: Thanks! For now I am just putting the value of the player to None when they disconnect. I'm sure there is probably a better way of doing this... but it works

Answer (score 2):

As per @Seb's comment, the del statement removes by key. If the key is not present in the list (the length of the list has decreased for example) then an IndexError is raised.

In your main loop and thread function, you'd be better served by passing the Player object by reference. Inside you player thread function, you'd then:

1. not need to read the player from the list by index, you'd just have the instance available to you
2. you can remove the player from the list using players.remove(player)

You'd also want to use your update function rather than re-assigning your player object each loop.